# How do I add extra columns to this UITableView and populate with data already fetched?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In the following code I fetch some data for a UITableView.

Currently, the table shows one column of data 'homeTeam'.

My desired output is to have multiple columns within the UITableView.

I have fetched the arrays for the other columns which can be seen in the code below.

```
import UIKit

class ShowResultsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var personalPlayerId: String?
var communityId: String?
var personalPlayer2Id: String?
var postString: String?

var homeTeam = [String?]()
var homePlayer = [String?]()
var homeGoals = [String?]()

var awayTeam = [String?]()
var awayPlayer = [String?]()
var awayGoals = [String?]()

var matchId = [String?]()

var tempResult: Int?

var selectedMatch: String?

var headToHead: Bool?

@IBOutlet weak var leagueTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.leagueTableView.delegate = self
    self.leagueTableView.dataSource = self


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.homeTeam.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let title = self.homeTeam[indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tempResult = indexPath.row

    if let tempShowResult = (self.homeTeam[tempResult!]){
        self.selectedMatch = tempShowResult
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.???.uk/???/getLeagueResults.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    if self.headToHead == true {
        self.postString = "player_id=\(self.personalPlayerId!)&player2_id=\(personalPlayer2Id!)&community_id=\(communityId!)";
    }else{
        if self.headToHead == false{
            self.postString = "player_id=\(self.personalPlayerId!)&community_id=\(communityId!)";
        }
    }

    request.httpBody = self.postString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                do{

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)


                        // GET DATA FOR TABLE COLUMNS


                            if let arr = json?["allPersonalLeagueStats"] as? [[String:String]] {
                                self.homeTeam = arr.flatMap { $0["player1_team"]!}
                                self.homePlayer = arr.flatMap { $0["player1_name"]!}
                                self.homeGoals = arr.flatMap { $0["player1_goals"]!}

                                self.awayTeam = arr.flatMap { $0["player2_team"]!}
                                self.awayPlayer = arr.flatMap { $0["player2_name"]!}
                                self.awayGoals = arr.flatMap { $0["player2_goals"]!}

                                self.matchId = arr.flatMap { $0["results_id"]!}
                            }


                       self.leagueTableView.reloadData()
                    }


                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }
    task.resume()


}


}
```

How do I add more columns to this table to show the extra columns; `home_player`, `home_goal`, `away_player`, `away_team`, `away_goals`?

I would like the output to represent the following in a table:

`+---------------+---------+-------+-------+------------+--------------+
| Bobby Charles | Man Utd |   2   |   3   |  Fiorentina| Andrew James |
| Ryan Stood    | Arsenal |   0   |   1   |  Chelsea   | Bobby Charles|
| Bobby Charles | Chelsea |   0   |   2   |  Liverpool | Ryan Stood   |
+---------------+---------+-------+-------+------------+--------------+`

Comment: To have collumns, not only rows, use `UICollectionView` instead of `UITableView`.

Comment: Great thanks - so is that the best approach for wanting to essentially show a list of results from football matches?  pulled from a results table in a database.

Comment: You can just use a custom cell (UITableViewCell).  You don't necessarily have to use UICollectionView.

Comment: @ElTomato - could you please expand and tell me how - or point me in the right direction.  I have looked but out doesn't seem to be covered in any details.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorial about custom UITableViewCell, read one, and try it, then once you understood what you are doing, customize it with you own needs (one label for the name, one for the team, one for the score, and so on.). Also, don't use an array for each element, they are linked, use a custom object/struct to keep them "synchronized".

Comment: that's fine - but i don't want to waste my time doing tutorials for UITableViewCell if it turns out i should be doing tutorials for UICollectionView.  Just looking for some concrete validation that it can be done using UITableView and i will.

Comment: Unrelated but you need to completely reorganize your data. Why do you have so many arrays? You should have a `struct` with all the different properties that represents one row of data. Then have a single array containing instances of that `struct` for each row. This will make your code so much simpler and make it easy to do things like sorting and filtering and searching.

Comment: that sounds a good idea rmaddy - i will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. take a UITableViewCell
2. Add six UILabels to this cell
3. As you having different arrays for each, in `cellForRowAtindexPath` add data to these labels.

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:    NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

           cell.label1.text = self.homeTeam[indexPath.row]
           cell.label2.text = self.homePlayer[indexPath.row]
           cell.label3.text = self.homeGoal[indexPath.row]
           cell.label4.text = self.awayTeam[indexPath.row]
           cell.label5.text = self.awayPlayer[indexPath.row]
           cell.label6.text = self.awayGoals[indexPath.row]

           return cell
   }
   ```

**Note:**
Maintaining that many arrays is not a good idea.

> Use **Struct** instead, to handle the data.it is easier and simpler

Answer (score 0):

Make sure what you exactly mean columns or row.

Your `cellForRowAtindexPath` is so improper. You haven't done anything there.

To answer your question, you will have to make an array appending `home_player`, `home_goal`, `away_player`, `away_team`, `away_goals` and then configure them in your `cellForRowAtindexPath` accordingly. Although there are other ways too to achieve the same.

Note: I would suggest you to read some tutorials on `UITableView`.

Comment: I have updated my question to show my desired output.  Can this be done using `cellForRowAtindexPath`?